# Is it possible to create a sparkline using apps script and not built in function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Google Spreadsheets and I'd like to customize the sparkline function beyond the given parameters that come with the `=sparkline()` function.

More specifically I want to create a bullet chart. I can create a stacked barchart by doing this: `=SPARKLINE(C9:E9,{"charttype","bar"})`

A stacked bar chart is half way to a bullet chart. [Here's](http://dealerdiagnostics.com/blog/2008/05/create-bullet-graphs-with-google-charts-in-7-easy-steps/) an example bullet chart using Google Charts API.

Given that blog post uses Google Charts API and that I'm currently using Google-Spreadsheets, stands to reason there may be a way to create a sparkline formula for a bullet chart (since I'm using 2 Google Services that are somewhat integrated).

I also just want to practice using GAS.

Ideally, I want to be able to create the sparklines using a function within a cell (similar to `=image()`). This is as opposed to creating a chart.

Any helpers? Is there a way to do this using a custom function built using GAS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create a chart or image with Custom Formula in Google Apps Script.  Because custom formulas run without special permissions, they can only access a limited subset of the services available to more general Apps Scripts.

See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced

Basically, custom formulas can return a single value, or an array of values, and that's the only way they can interact with the spreadsheet.

In order to create charts with Apps Script, you need to use either a sidebar or a function called from a custom menu, which would then allow you to use the Charts service.

Comment: Thanks for the info. If I used a custom menu function, would I be able to use custom script to create the sparklines, like in an =image() function? Or will it still only allow an actual image?

Comment: I've never tried, but I imagine you should be able to coax the LineCharts you can create via the Charts service into having a sparkline type appearance, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/line-chart-builder .    I haven't done much with work with charts so I can't back this up with experience.